# What is the name of the top of a hemisphere?

Tags: geometry, terminology

I need to refer to the "top" of a hemisphere - the "highest point" on a hemisphere.  I am thinking it must be called the "apex" of the hemisphere, but I am not sure.

Comment: North pole?${}$

Comment: Agreed, David.  It is picturesque and entirely accurate.

Comment: @David, I wonder what the Australians would have to say about that.

Comment: I asked an Australian once if they orient their globes with the South Pole uppermost, but he said no, they orient them the same way that everyone else does.

Comment: Just plain "pole" ought to be fine...

Comment: il colmo dellagran secca http://books.google.ca/books?id=jfVFeveiJLIC&pg=PA259&lpg=PA259&dq=name+for+the++highest+point+of+hemisphere&source=bl&ots=AziuNhW1uA&sig=3JrkugQwAI_W6pWzEoyDl6yGTeM&hl=en&sa=X&ei=MbIUUKbFOYimrQGshYFo&ved=0CDEQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=name%20for%20the%20%20highest%20point%20of%20hemisphere&f=false

Comment: The Bald Spot. ${}$

Comment: @Mark, I guess I really meant the implicit assumption that the hemisphere is the northern one. The question does say "top", but ideally the answer should be independent of whether the hemisphere is placed with the convex part facing up, down, or to the side...

Answer (score 1):

The term [Chebyshev center](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev_center) is well established, despite the confusing "alternative" definition in the first paragraph of the article. A Chebyshev center of a set $A$ in metric space $X$ is a point $c\in X$ (which may or may not be unique) which minimizes $\sup_{a\in A} d(a,c)$. If $X$ is a hemisphere with either extrinsic (chordal) or intrinsic (Riemannian) metric, the Chebyshev center of $X$ is the point you want to describe. This description is less intuitive than North Pole, but is invariant under rigid motions.

(Aside: a very nice application of Chebyshev centers to a [fixed point problem](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/s00222-011-0363-2).)

Comment: Perhaps I can simply refer to it as the "center" of the hemisphere.

Comment: @bobobobo But that may be confused with the geometric center of the sphere. On second thought: Chevyshev center is what I'd use for a generic set, but for this specific shape *pole* is better. You can define it in a few words even without imposing a particular orientation of the hemisphere: the pole is the intersection of hemisphere with its axis of symmetry.